# Vuejs different kinds of entry points are confusing

Tags: vue.js

I created two Vuejs project. 
The 1st one main.js  looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";



Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

The second one looks like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import router from "./router";

import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";


Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

please someone explain me the difference between this codes espacially the the new vue instance creation in two differnt ways?

Comment: Essentially just two ways to accomplish the same thing. Lots of discussion on it here: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/issues/29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For The 1st one main.js:

First you must understand all the render:

The render: h => h(App) is shorthand for:

```
render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement(App);
}
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
render: (createElement) => {
    return createElement(App);
}
```

Which can again be shortened to (with h being an alias to createElement as noted above):

```
render: (h) => {
    return h(App);
}
```

Which is then shortened further to (using ES6 "fat arrow" syntax):

```
render: h => h(App);
```

The H, It comes from the term "hyperscript", which is commonly used in many virtual-dom implementations. "Hyperscript" itself stands for "script that generates HTML structures" because HTML is the acronym for "hyper-text markup language".

And the $mount allows you to explicitly mount the Vue instance when you need to. This means that you can delay the mounting of your vue instance until a particular element exists in your page or some async process has finished, which can be particularly useful when adding vue to legacy apps which inject elements into the DOM, I've also used this frequently in testing when I've wanted to use the same vue instance across multiple tests:

```
// Create the vue instance but don't mount it
const vm = new Vue({
  template: '<div>I\'m mounted</div>',
  created(){
    console.log('Created');
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log('Mounted');
  }
});

// Some async task that creates a new element on the page which we can mount our instance to.
setTimeout(() => {
   // Inject Div into DOM
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.id = 'async-div';
   document.body.appendChild(div);

  vm.$mount('#async-div');
},1000)
```

For The second one, I strongly recommend you to look over the current  Vue documentation:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Having all of your template code in an App.vue (and none in your index.html’s #app div) allows us to use the runtime-only version of Vue which is smaller than the full version.

but lets break it up:

1. `el: '#app',` will look in your index.html file for a div `<div id="app"></div>`;
2. the router, will allow you to use globally the router;
3. components: { App }, import your App.vue, and all component you have imported there, generally you put in this file people often put: side bar components, headers components, navigable stuff;

4.`template: "<App/>"`, will create a div in you HTML with the id="app" only after it import you App.vue components imported there or HTML created in this file, all the content from you files will be wrapped by this div. People often use `<router-view>` to load the router pages components.

This second instance have the purpose of Having a cleaner index.html and having all the stuff in the App.vue